# Walmart plant ID

Tags: identification

I got this a number of years ago in the clearance section at Walmart. It was a collection of perennials in a pot. We planted them in the garden and this one continues to persist.

Anyone know what it is?[image: perennial]
[image: perennial]

Comment: What zone are you in?

Comment: @blackthumb zone 10a

Comment: Well it looks extraordinarily like a Canna indica  - but they usually flower at around a foot or more in height and in cooler  climates, not before May/June.Image of flower here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/prune-cannas-63998.html but I'm finding it hard to believe it is a Canna...

Comment: @Bamboo I think you are almost right.  It looks like a Canna Lilly for sure.  Maybe this one: https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/255414/#b

Comment: @1800-94-Jenny but the height of the plant is still wrong .... the one you  link to, like all the ones I know, reaches up to 2 feet in height before flowering

Answer (score 3):

It's a canna lily. It grows prolifically in India and I've seen this type of canna quite a few times.